# For unequal set sizes in PSI: why should the party with fewer elements use cuckoo hash rather than simple hash?

Tags: hash, multiparty-computation, private-set-intersection

Most PSI papers usually use hash-to-bin to improve the number of comparsons.

For unequal set sizes in 2PSI, I have read [CCS17](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/299.pdf), which designs a PSI protocol for unequal size. The party with fewer elements use cuckoo hash, The party with more elements use simple hash.

I want to know the reason why the party with fewer elements should use cuckoo hash rather than simple hash, and why the party with much more elements should use simple hash rather than cuckoo hash. the reason may be as follows: if the the party with more elements use cuckoo hash, because cuckoo hash requires each bin stores at most one element, then this party need more bin.